# How to make an insert query in DQL

Tags: insert, dql, doctrine-1.2

I'm working with symfony and I would like to know how I can do a simple insert using the doctrine:dql task.

```
./symfony doctrine:dql "<what should I put here?>"
```

Comment: I have a feeling you can only do SELECTs as only "FROM ..." seems to work and it implies there's a SELECT in front. Easiest alternative would probably be to run a specific fixture file which does the INSERT.

Comment: @Tom: you can also do UPDATE and DELETE requests whith this command. So why not DELETE requests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You [officially](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#types-of-dql-queries) cannot INSERT using DQL. Only SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: Actually now you can: 
The \Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder supports building SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries. 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: @SimonBerton The link you provide is for the SQL Query Builder of the DBAL sub-project, not the DQL Query Builder. They are two unrelated query builders.

Answer (score 2):

With Doctrine you don´t use INSERT´s. This type of query must be made by the Entity Manager, through its method PERSIST.

Comment: I slightly modified the tags, the question was about doctrine 1.2 . But your answer could be interesting anyway... +1